# How to export Environment variables to a text file

Tags: windows-xp, environment-variables

I want to have a look into my Environment variables as a text file into XP Professional.
Is there any way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using the `set` at the command prompt will list all of your environment variables. So, you can just pipe the output of the `set` command to a file, like this:

```
set > "\path\to\file.txt"
```